# Computer Locking Up Frequently

Tags: windows-7, freeze

I have a pre-built computer (Dell XPS 8300 to be specific) and it's been working fine for the past year however last week I started to randomly lock up on me. Lock up as in the screen would freeze and any sound playing would loop/stutter. Keyboard input as well as mouse input is also ignored. There is also no BSOD after 5 minutes of leaving it like that. In order to fix it I need to perform a hard reboot.

I have checked my CPU and RAM usage during these lockups and they are completely random. They occur when 2GB of ram is being used to 10GB. My CPU usage during these lockups also fluctuates, from around 10% to 60%. I have not installed any new software over the last couple weeks and and performing a system restore to about 3 days before the lock ups began has not yielded any results. I also tried updating my drivers multiple times to no avail.

This has been occurring at least once a day sometimes even 4 or 5 times a day since last week and I would appreciate it if somebody could help me.

**Computer Specs**

- CPU: Intel i7-2600
- RAM: 16 GB
- OS: Windows 7 65-bit
- GPU: AMD Radeon HD 640 (Not Using AMD Overdrive)
- Sound card: THX TruStudio PC

Not sure what the other parts are but I do know they're OEM.

I also have a wireless card that I installed last year but that hasn't caused me any problems in the past. It's a D-Link DWA-556 Xtreme N PCIe.

**SpeedFan Results**

- HDD: 42 Degrees Celsius
- GPU: 67 Degrees Celsius
- Core 0: 58 Degrees Celsius
- Core 1: 62 Degrees Celsius
- Core 3: 51 Degrees Celsius
- Core 4: 52 Degrees Celsius

My BIOS does not show me the recommended temperature for each of my parts by the way so I have no way of knowing what is a safe operating temperature for everything.

Comment: Sounds like the the HDD is failing I would replace it.

Comment: Have you checked your RAM with something like [Memtest](http://www.memtest.org)? I agree that the HDD could be failing but you are having I/O problems which, frankly, can point to a lot of components. You can also try and test your HDD with a SMART sensor programs or even try and do a non-OS chkdsk run. Other than that, I'd say more testing is needed. By the way, you gave me a slight chuckle when I saw your "65-bit" OS. Well done :)

Comment: @redknightalex - I have had memory problems in the past and they have generated BSOD.  I have had hdd problems, and while I personally got BSOD, they wouldn't actually restart my computer and lock up in the process of dumping a file ( the system drive was actually being ejected ).

Comment: Ramhound: Like I said to cybernard I ran a full disk check and nothing came up. I have no had an BSODs occur within the last week. redknightalex: I'll check my RAM and report back with the results.

Answer (score 1):

First,
Run and administrative "command prompt"

```
chkdsk /R c:
```

Say yes went it asks if you want to do it on the next reboot.

reboot.

wait patently for a several hours.

Your temperatures seems fine.  How is dust level?  As part of periodic system maintenance you should probably blow it out with a can of compressed air anyway.

Comment: Ran a full disk check last night while I was asleep. Can't really say anything about it cause well I was asleep but I'm assuming there were no problems considering how i woke up with my computer on the Windows lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

Ran Memtest and ran into I think it was 64400 errors in the first 5 minutes so I'm gonna be replacing my RAM. Thanks for help guys!